# Build array from two hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, hash, geojson

I try to build json with geojson datas.

In my controller :

```
def index
 .... 
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render json: { type: 'FeatureCollection', features: pois_geojson + tracks_geojson} }
end
```

and for show

```
def show
  ...
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render json: { type: 'FeatureCollection', features: poi_geojson + track_geojson} }
  end
```

For index, all work fine and my json is good. I call this method for build json.

Methods for show

```
def poi_geojson
    {
     type: 'Feature',
     RGeo::GeoJSON.encode(@poi.lonlat),
  properties: {
    name: @poi.name,
    :'marker-color' => '#00607d',
    :'marker-symbol' => 'circle',
    :'marker-size' => 'medium'
  }
}
end


def track_geojson
    {
      type: 'Feature',
      geometry: RGeo::GeoJSON.encode(@track.path),
      properties: {
        :'color' => '#ff7800',
        :'weight' => '5',
        :'opacity' => '0.65'
      }
    }
end
```

Methods for index

```
def pois_geojson
  @pois.map do |poi|
    {
      type: 'Feature',
      RGeo::GeoJSON.encode(poi.lonlat)
      properties: {
        name: poi.name,
        :'marker-color' => '#00607d',
        :'marker-symbol' => 'circle',
        :'marker-size' => 'medium'
      }
    }
  end
end

def tracks_geojson
  @tracks.map do |track|
    {
      type: 'Feature',
      geometry: RGeo::GeoJSON.encode(track.path),
      properties: {
        :'color' => '#ff7800',
        :'weight' => '5',
        :'opacity' => '0.65'
      }
    }
   end
end
```

As you can see, the methods are similars, but I don't understand why for index it work fine, and not for the show.

I have this error :

> `undefined method '+' for #` 
>   for this line :
>   `format.json { render json: { type: 'FeatureCollection', features: poi_geojson + track_geojson} }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `+` method for hash instances, to form an array from two hashes you can do the following:

```
[pois_geojson, tracks_geojson]
```

The reason why this works for `pois_geojson` and `tracks_geojson` is because both of them are already arrays.